# opengl simple example without glwf/glut

Tags: c, winapi, opengl, glew

I am trying to write a basic OpenGL loop (without GLWF and GLUT; only GLEW), which does nothing but clears the window.
However, the window keeps being white, the color of the window is not cleared to red.

Could you find the error why the code doesn't work?
Any other advice about my code? What can be made better?

```
/*Window is created using CreateWindowExA()*/ 
/* glewInit() etc  */
    RenderingContext = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(DeviceContext, 0, version_attribs);
    if (!wglMakeCurrent(DeviceContext, RenderingContext))
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("Error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }   
    bool Running = true;
    while (Running){
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            // Simply clear the window with red
            static const GLfloat red[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
            glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red);
            // here some other code
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any gl-command will be executed on the **current context**.

You use `wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);` which means: "exclude all gl-commands for this thread"

Instead use `wglMakeCurrent(this_window_device, the_context_I_want_to_use);`

EDIT:

Also, the rendering is done to the *back frame buffer* (I'm supposing you are using a double buffer pixelformat). To show it into the window (front frame buffer) you need to call `wglSwapBuffers`.

EDIT 2:

I recomend you read the whole of [wiki about creaating a context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)).

It shows an example of window and context creation.

Comment: this doesn't work, still write screen. I have tried wglMakeCurrent(DeviceContext, RenderingContext);

Comment: I've edited my answer. Anyhow you post so few code that there may be a lot of other things failing.

Comment: it works, thank you, the screen is red :)